# how to send a jpeg image in r.drawable as an attachment to email?

Tags: android

Currently I'm developing an app which sends the image from `r.drawable` to email as an attachment, I have uploaded the code for my app, it gets force close in emulator,and logcat shows nullpointerexception. kindly help me to solve this.

I have changed the image(jpeg) into bit map, and converted it into a byte array and ,ithink that this byte array shows nullpointerexception in logcat, I have also tried  giving 100 or 10,0000 instead of 0 in line `myLogo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, bos)`. And still my app gets force close.showing the same error in log cat. Hoping for a solution. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.email;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class home extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aish);
    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ids=ed1.getText().toString();
            String id[]={ids};
            String sub=ed2.getText().toString();
            String msg=ed3.getText().toString();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            myLogo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, bos);
            Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            in.setData(Uri.parse("MailTo:"));
            in.setType("plain/text");
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,id);
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,sub);
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msg);
            in.setType("image/jpg");
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,bos.toByteArray());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "Email"));

            }
            });
            }
}
```

Comment: `i think that this byte array shows nullpointerexception in logcat`, well show us the logcat and we'll know for sure!

Comment: can you post the logcat please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly attach the image in drawable like this,

```
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.aish));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are attaching a `null` (nothing).

see in here

```
    in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,bos.toByteArray());
```

you are attaching `bos.toByteArray` and `bos` is the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
So basically you are attaching a `bytearray` not an `image`.

try this:

```
File jpegfile = new File(imageDir, "yourfilename.jpeg");

Uri jpegurl = Uri.fromFile(jpegfile);

        in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, jpegurl);
```